# Show uniform convergence of the sequence $f_n(x) = ( x-x^n/n)$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show uniform convergence of the sequence $(x-x^n/n)$ on $[0,1]$

To start with, i am not even able to see what the point was limit of this sequence should be. Little confused. like for $x=0$ I think the limit should be $0$ and for $x=1$ it should be $1$ and for values in between i think it should be $x$. Is that correct ? How do i further show its uniform convergence ?

Comment: Yes, the sequence converges pointwise to $f(x)=x$. You need to show that $|x-(x-x^n/n)|=x^n/n$ can be is uniformly small on $[0,1]$ provided $n$ is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of functions $f_n$:  $\left(x-\frac{x^n}n\right)_n$ is point-wise convergent to the function $f\colon x\mapsto x$ and we have
$$\forall x\in[0,1],\quad|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{x^n}n\le \frac1n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
so the convergence is uniform.

Comment: $\uparrow{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Your guess for the limit is $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x$. Let's see if that works.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, then

$$|f(x) - f_n(x)| = \left|x - (x - \frac{x^n}{n})\right| = \frac{x^n}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$$

for $n \geq N = \lceil\varepsilon^{-1}\rceil$. So $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Comment: nice !! i was thinking in the right direction. just was not confident. Thanks a lot